# Retina @2x versions of graphics not being used

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, retina-display

I'm working on an iPhone game and for some reason it is not using the @2x versions of many of my images. Do you have any idea why this might be? When building the UI in the storyboard, should I be placing the @2x versions instead? They look too big when I try that. Do you have any idea why it wouldn't use my @2x graphics?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use @2x version of the graphics directly in the code. But they have to be added in your project and Xcode will inject the @2x version for newer devices like iPhone 4S and iPhone 5.

For example, one image name in your app is myImage, you have two version of this image named myImage and myImage@2x (the one for retina display devices), but in your code you will only add myImage and not myImage@2x but as myImage@2x is added in your project, it will be used for Retina devices.

Thanks!